# SQL query having CASE WHEN EXISTS statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I trying to create a SQL query with a `CASE WHEN EXISTS` clause in SQL Server. I assume I am doing something wrong as when I run the `SELECT * FROM [Christmas_Sale]` it takes forever for SQL to load the code.

```
CREATE VIEW [Christmas_Sale]
AS
   SELECT  
       C.*,
       CASE 
          WHEN EXISTS (SELECT S.Sale_Date
                       FROM [Christmas_Sale] s
                       WHERE C.ID = S.ID) 
              THEN 0 
              ELSE 1 
       END AS ChristmasSale
   FROM 
       [Customer_Detail] C ;
```

I'm trying to write a sub select which I need to return a 1 if Sale_Date= 1 and 0 for anything else.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of your query looks ok. But since your stated:

> I'm trying to write a sub select which I need to return a 1 **if Sale_Date= 1** and 0 for anything else.

... Then you could rephrase your query by adding one more condition in the `WHERE` clause of the subquery:

```
CREATE VIEW [Christmas_Sale]AS
SELECT  
    C.*,
    CASE  WHEN EXISTS ( 
        SELECT 1 
        FROM [Christmas_Sale] s
        WHERE C.ID = S.ID and S.Sale_Date = 1
     )  THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS ChristmasSale
FROM [Customer_Detail] C ;
```

If a record exists in `[Christmas_Sale]` with the corresponding `ID` and `Sale_Date = 1`, then `ChristmasSale` will have value `1`, else it will display `0`.

Answer (score 0):

This query looks correct:

```
CREATE VIEW [Christmas_Sale] AS
   SELECT C.*,
          (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                             FROM [Christmas_Sale] s
                             WHERE C.ID = S.ID
                            ) 
                THEN 0 ELSE 1
            END) AS ChristmasSale
    FROM [Customer_Detail] C ;
```

If performance is an issue, you want an index on `Christmas_Sale(ID)`.

Note that the `SELECT S.Sale_Date` in the subquery is meaningless, because `EXISTS` checks for *rows* not *columns*.  Hence, I replaced it with the simpler `1`.